# How to add Social Lookup sidebar in Service console?

Tags: service-cloud-console, social

As shown on the right of this image:

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*T5fVtpPdlSw0FQywTHtFKg.png]

I can't see it in the console builder or in the setup menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the component here:

/packagingSetupUI/ipLanding.app?apvId=04t36000000kFgu

Just prepend the link above with your sandbox instance, for example:

https://me.lightning.force.com/packagingSetupUI/ipLanding.app?apvId=04t36000000kFgu

The package is not generally available but it works great.